# Making missing time slots and filling in 0 values in a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas series as such 
(that i've made by doing a groupby a two columns
`divvy_df.groupby(['from_station_name', 'starttime']).size()` ):

```
from_station_name       starttime          
900 W Harrison          2014-07-01 08:00:00    1
                        2014-07-01 10:00:00    1
                        2014-07-01 11:00:00    1
                        2014-07-01 12:00:00    1
                        2014-07-01 13:00:00    1
                        2014-07-01 16:00:00    1
                        2014-07-01 17:00:00    3
                        2014-07-01 22:00:00    1
                        2014-07-02 01:00:00    1
                        2014-07-02 08:00:00    1
                        2014-07-02 12:00:00    2
                        ...
```

As you can see, the resulting series shows the number of times that starttime is logged for that station name. I'd like to make it somehow though, so that the *missing* time slots are created and filled in with a value of 0. Is that possible?

So I'd want something like this:

```
from_station_name       starttime          
    900 W Harrison          2014-07-01 00:00:00    0
                            2014-07-01 01:00:00    0
                            2014-07-01 02:00:00    0
                            2014-07-01 03:00:00    0
                            ...
                            2014-07-01 08:00:00    1
                            2014-07-01 09:00:00    0   
                            2014-07-01 10:00:00    1
                            2014-07-01 11:00:00    1
                            2014-07-01 12:00:00    1
                            2014-07-01 13:00:00    0
                            ...
                            2014-07-01 22:00:00    1
                            2014-07-01 23:00:00    0
                            2014-07-02 00:00:00    0
```

What's the best way to get something like this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when you have a Series, `ts`, with DatetimeIndex, you can expand it to 
include new dates by using `ts.reindex`, or `ts.asfreq` or `ts.resample`.
Since `ts.reindex` has a `fill_value` parameter for filling in missing values, I
think it will be easiest to use `ts.reindex` in this case.

However, in this problem, `ts` has a MultiIndex with `from_station_name` and
`starttime` levels.

So the first step is to move the `from_station_name` level out of the index.
There are two options. You can use `reset_index` to move it to a column, or use
`unstack` to move it into a new column index level. I think `unstacking` with

```
ts = ts.unstack(level=0)
```

is the better choice here because with the other option (using `reset_index`)
you run into issues related to duplicate dates in the index, and the problem of
back-filling and forward-filling missing `from_station_name` values.

Now the Series has a single level DatetimeIndex, so you can `reindex` like this:

```
index = pd.date_range('2014-07-01', '2014-07-03', freq='H')
ts = ts.reindex(index, fill_value=0)
```

And now undo the `unstack` operation, thus moving the column index level back
into the row index:

```
ts = ts.stack()
ts = ts.swaplevel(0,1)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.Series({('900 W Harrison', '2014-07-01 08:00:00'): 1,
 ('900 W Harrison', '2014-07-01 10:00:00'): 1,
 ('900 W Harrison', '2014-07-01 11:00:00'): 1,
 ('900 W Harrison', '2014-07-01 12:00:00'): 1,
 ('900 W Harrison', '2014-07-01 13:00:00'): 1,
 ('900 W Harrison', '2014-07-01 16:00:00'): 1,
 ('900 W Harrison', '2014-07-01 17:00:00'): 3,
 ('900 W Harrison', '2014-07-01 22:00:00'): 1,
 ('900 W Harrison', '2014-07-02 01:00:00'): 1,
 ('900 W Harrison', '2014-07-02 08:00:00'): 1,
 ('900 W Harrison', '2014-07-02 12:00:00'): 2})

ts = ts.unstack(level=0)
# ensure ts.index is a DatetimeIndex
ts.index = pd.to_datetime(ts.index)
index = pd.date_range('2014-07-01', '2014-07-03', freq='H')
ts = ts.reindex(index, fill_value=0)
ts = ts.stack()
ts = ts.swaplevel(0,1)
ts = ts.sortlevel()
print(ts)
```

yields

```
900 W Harrison  2014-07-01 00:00:00    0
                2014-07-01 01:00:00    0
                2014-07-01 02:00:00    0
                2014-07-01 03:00:00    0
                2014-07-01 04:00:00    0
                2014-07-01 05:00:00    0
                2014-07-01 06:00:00    0
                2014-07-01 07:00:00    0
                2014-07-01 08:00:00    1
                2014-07-01 09:00:00    0
                2014-07-01 10:00:00    1
                ...
                2014-07-02 21:00:00    0
                2014-07-02 22:00:00    0
                2014-07-02 23:00:00    0
                2014-07-03 00:00:00    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: holy crap, this looks amazing. thanks for answering - i'll read thru it now!

Comment: for some reason, everything looks good but the filled 0 values go away when I run the .stack() line. What was showing up as a nice table with NaNs in all the empty values, go away in that step...

Comment: this is the intermediary step I needed to get your output - still very excellent:

ts = ts.fillna(0)